# Show that $S$ and $2^{S}$ are not equinumerous. (Not bijective?)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have tried to look for a problem the same as mine, but I have not been too lucky, or if I did I had trouble applying that solution to my problem. Any help would be appreciated. I know how to solve this problem, but I'm afraid it would someone "cheap" because it is just a fact I found.

Let $S$ be any set.  Let $2^{S} =\{f\mid f\colon S\to\{0,1\}\}$. Then $S$ and $2^{S}$ are not equinumerous.

Now, I believe the "cheap" way I found out how to do this is to use the fact that the there is a bijection between $2^{S}$ and $\mathcal{P}(S)$, but there is no bijection between a set and it's power set.

I was given a hint to assume there is a bijection $f\colon S\to2^{S}$, and to copy the method used in Cantor's Theorem. I went through this theorem a few weeks ago. Also, I just looked at in my text and on Proofwiki, but I am still having trouble.

Edit: I forgot to mention I am just taking an introductory logic class. The only thing we have done with Cantor's Theorem is prove that the powerset of integers is non enumerable.

Answer (score 3):

In Cantor's theorem, as well as here, you don't need to assume towards contradiction that there is a bijection.

**HINT:** The proof of Cantor's theorem says that given a function $F\colon S\to\mathcal P(S)$, then the set $D_F=\{s\in S\mid s\notin F(s)\}$ is not in the image of $F$. Translate this $D_F$ into a binary string indexed by $S$.

(Conclude from this that there cannot be a surjective function, let alone a bijection function, between the two sets.)

Comment: I can follow Cantor's Theorem perfectly well. However, as I stated, one of my problems is not being able to apply it to the problem I was given.

Comment: If a subset of $S$ is a binary $S$-string, where $b_s=0$ means that $s$ is not in that subset; given $F\colon S\to 2^S$, how can you define a string which corresponds to $D_F$?

Comment: I'm sorry. I am not familiar with the notion of a binary $S-string$

Comment: It's an ad-hoc term, which I had hoped you'd understand as a function from $S$ to $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Asaf, when you say $D_F$ into a binary string indexed by s are you talking about the indicator function? I'm sorry, but this is a little over my head. I forgot to mention I am just taking an introductory logic class. The only thing we have done with Cantor's Theorem is prove that the powerset of integers is non enumerable.

Comment: Yes, you can think about a binary string indexed by $S$ as an indicator function of a subset of $S$.

Comment: Ahhh... Thank you. I am going to try to mess with this a little more.

Answer (score 0):

$S$ a set of people, $F\colon S \to \mathcal{P}(S)$, $F(s) = \{\text{people shaved by } s \}$. Consider the barber $b$,  somebody who shaves exactly those people who do not shave themselves, i.e. $F(b) = \{ s \ | \ s \not \in F(s) \}$.  Does the barber shave himself? Or not?

Obs: The barber's paradox should ask the yes/no question:" does the barber shave himself?" rather than : " who shaves the barber?" . There could be several people shaving the same person ( compare  with other actions).

Comment: Oh how I despise that barber paradox thing. I always found it to be more confusing!

Comment: Oh, it's just that $b$ cannot be from $S$. It is really Cantor's argument.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently, you can prove there is no surjective function $f: S\to 2^S$. See my formal proof of this at [Cantor's Theorem](http://www.dcproof.com/CountableL3.htm) in the DC Proof format.

Answer (score 0):

- Combine Cantor's theorem with **prop 1.17.19** to show $X\nsim 2^X$

[image]

Comment: This is just way too lazy.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft which textbook is this from?